# MSEDGE replaceState | test if method is supported

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, hashbang

BROWSER: [Edge 12.10158](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/try-microsoft-edge)

Snippet:

```
window.history.replaceState({page: fragment},'','/demo/'+fragment);
```

This works in all other browsers as expected (including IE 11); However, when using this in Edge i get the error: `unspecified error`.

So naturally i wrote a conditional to return if the method exist.

```
return (typeof window.history.replaceState == "function")
```

This returns true, so the method replaceState is intended to be supported in MSEDGE.

> **What are some better alternative to test if this method is supported or not?**
>
> *iv'e added hashbang to the tags because this is part of the hashbang*
> *technique and i'm sure others will face this issue in the future.*

---

**UPDATE**: *This solves the unspecified error, but i would prefer not to emulate.*

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```